# Get event ids of all events in eventAfterAllRender fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have downloaded the fullcalendar source code and integrated as per my choice as shown in below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events:'getCalData&ver='+ver+'&choice='+choice+'&weekNo='+weekNo,
  defaultDate:startDate
});
```

and now I want to add a button to each event,I did as follows

```
 eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element, view){    
   $('.fc-event').each(function(){
     $(this).css('position','relative');
     $(this).append('<a class="add_event_label" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: #000;text-align: center;padding: 6px;background: #FFE6C4;border: 1px solid #555;border-radius: 5px;margin: 0px 18px;cursor: pointer;">Sign - Up</a><br>');
   });                             
 },
```

works fine.

My requirement is that I need all ids of events on `eventAfterAllRender`.I have searched for this but nothing works fine.Please let me know the correct way to achieve this.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow the code

```
 eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element, view){
          var events =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')
                 for(var i=0; i< events.length; i++) {
                    var eventsid = events[i].id;
                }
          }
```

eventsid carries the id of event